# Rewrite local var assignment in

Tags: scala, variable-assignment, rewriting

I would like to write this in Scala:

```
var b: Map[String, Int] = Map()
def method() = {
  def a_=(i: Int) = b += "method" -> i
  // ...
  a = 2
}
```

But this complains saying that a is not defined. Why is that? I thought `a = ...` was rewritten to `a_=(...)`.

**Solution**: Thanks to Jörg, i works, one has to provide the getter and make the method top-level:

```
var b: Map[String, Int] = Map()
def a_=(i: Int) = b += "method" -> i
def a: Int = ??? // Dummy
def method() = {
  // ...
  a = 2
}
```

This compiles.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rewrite the assignment operator?

Comment: Previously, I had a var `a`, but since I refactored the code elsewhere, I needed to assign it with another method.

Comment: I think this is meant more as a way to provide a "nice" API for users of your class. Not really something you would use with local variables and local methods. In Java you also don't have getters and setters (what this pattern basically is) for local variables.

Comment: Whatever the original meaning and what should or should not written in Scala, whatever the style, I found the solution above. Thanks for pondering about the semantics of this approach though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that? I thought `a = ...` was rewritten to `a_=(...)`.

No.

1. You need both a getter *and* a setter for the re-write to take effect.
2. The re-write only happens when there is something to re-write, i.e. field access of an `object`, `class`, or `trait`.

See [section 6.15 *Assignments* of the Scala Language Specifiation](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> **If `x` is a parameterless function defined in some template**, and **the same template** contains a setter function `x_=` as member, then the assignment `x = e` is interpreted as the invocation `x_=(e)` of that setter function.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot override assignment operator, since it's a reserved word. what you can do is this:

```
object BAndA {
  var b: Map[String, Int] = Map()

  def a = b // getter
  def a_=(i: Int) = b += "method" -> i // setter
}

object Test extends App {
  import BAndA._

  a = 1
  println(b)
}
```

getter is requried

Comment: You just gave a meaning to the assignment operator. I did not intend to override it. See, it is possible.